# How to use a CRF layer in Tensorflow 2 (using tfa.text)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, named-entity-recognition, crf

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size,output_dim=100,input_length=input_len,weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))

model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size_label, activation="softmax")))
model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```

I have built a Bi-lstm model for NER Tagging and now I want to introduce CRF layer in it. I am confused how can I insert CRF layer using Tensorflow

```
tfa.text.crf_log_likelihood(
    inputs,
    tag_indices,
    sequence_lengths,
    transition_params=None
)
```

I found this in tfa.txt and have 3 queries regarding this function:
1. How do I pass these arguments?
2. Do I have to use output of this as loss (negative of log_likelihood) in compiler.
Can someone plz help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for this solution too, and I guess you should create a custom class to wrap the `tfa.text.crf_log_likelihood` method, and then integrate it in `keras.Sequence`.

Maybe something like https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/723#issuecomment-559636561

Or even more *pytorch-style*, like this https://github.com/saiwaiyanyu/bi-lstm-crf-ner-tf2.0/blob/master/model.py